# relative references for google sheets scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google sheets script that hides and unhides rows based on a drop down menu within the spreadsheet. While working within the spreadsheet I would like to be able to insert or delete rows and have the script update to hide and unhide rows at the same points. For example:

My script unhides rows 100-125 based on a "Yes" value in a cell L77. I need to insert 10 rows while working in the spreadsheet. I want the script to now unhide or hide rows 100-135 without having to manually change the row numbers within the script.

Here's my script.

```
function hideUnhideRows(hideOrUnhide, rowNum) {
  if (hideOrUnhide == "hide") {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().hideRows(rowNum)
  }
  else {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().showRows(rowNum)  
  }
}

function onEdit(e) {  
  if (e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() == "Sheet 1") {
    switch (e.range.getA1Notation()) {
      case "L77":
        if (e.value == "Yes") {
          for (var i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
            hideUnhideRows("unhide", 100 + i);
          }
        }
      else {
         for (var i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
           hideUnhideRows("hide", 100 + i);
         }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What's your specific question? What have you tried to do? Questions which are simply "Make my script do what I want" are not generally well received. I recommend you use a NamedRange.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I am new to scripting and this site. Not sure how to ask my question without giving an example, so here's another attempt. If I create a formula in a spreadsheet that references, say cell B10 and later add 10 rows, that formula will reference B20. If I delete 5 rows the  formula now references B15. My question is, how do I get a script that references row 10 to know that I've added 10 rows and now reference row 20?

Comment: The only thing I've done so far is to anticipate any future needs  and add a bunch of rows within the spreadsheet. I plan to then change the script accordingly. But that doesn't help down the road if I end up needing more rows than I anticipate.